# jquery- How to get the list item id of the parent and the position of an li item

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i would like to access li (id-67) via li (id-68)

i tried `$("#68").parent('li').attr("id")` and `$("#68").parent().parent('li').attr("id")`

and could not grab the id 67.. Any idea thanks!

[image]

Comment: $("#68").parent().parent('li').attr("id"); should work ,make sure if your code in the document ready block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery.fn.prev() :

```
$("#68").prev();
```

Comment: but the problem is when you make that node as a root node it still grab previous li's value which is not desired. it should only grab parent li if there is one

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`jQuery.fn.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to get to the closest parent `li`:

```
$('#68').parents('li:eq(0)').attr('id');
```

Comment: i tried it on sortable stop function and it returns itself instead of 68

stop: function (event, ui) {
                    idListItem = ui.item[0].id;
                    newListIndex = ui.item.index() + 1;
                    pageId = ui.item[0].id;


 alert($("#" + ui.item[0].id).closest('li').attr('id'));

Comment: Oh, yes, you have to use `.parents()`, not closest. Closest starts with itself. I'll edit my answer. >.<

Comment: alert($("#" + ui.item[0].id).parents('li:eq(0)').attr('id'));  it does not work grab the value neither